# Creating custom images for PyTorch Dataset

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, dataset

I'm trying to create a dataset for training a robot in a 2D world.
The World is going to have labels like "free", "unknown", "obstacle" to identify different components of the map.
This will most likely be with matrices using integers for the labels e.g. free=1, unknown=2 etc.

I want to use this dataset to train a CNN to learn the value of each state in the map.
The current plan is to break this world down into multiple binary matrices to separate the different labels.
So, eventually the neural net will have input like feeding in RGB images (but the different matrix layers here will represent the different labels).

I was looking at the DataLoader class in Pytorch and it allows us to create custom datasets.
However, in my dataset I don't have .jpg files, but separate matrix layers to represent the different labels in the map at each state.
Does anyone know how I can create a dataset like the one I want in PyTorch?

Comment: Build a custom dataset class with 3 methods `__init__, __len__, and __getitem__`. 
`__getitem__` method need to return a tuple (matrix,label) from your custom dataset.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this out!

Comment: @TrọngVăn - would it be possible to use a dataset as such? -> ['image' : [matrix_label1, matrix_label2, matrix_label3], 'label' : label_value]

Comment: Some torch functions like `Conv2d` need 4 dimension data type `(B,C,H,W)` but not a list. If you use `matrix_labels` you can try to concatenate them to 3 dimension data type `(C,H,W)`.